# How to Disable Color Options?

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, theme-options, custom-background

This question is related to my [earlier question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/where-is-default-wp-head-implemented), but I think it's specific enough to qualify as a standalone question.

I am modifying an existing theme (the Twenty Ten theme that ships with WordPress), and I would like to completely control the colors used. The Admin Screen allows the administrator to select a background color, and this seems to be implemented in one of the actions that are automatically registered to the `wp_head` hook (listed by Bainternet [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/where-is-default-wp-head-implemented)).

So I would like to do two things:

- Remove the *Color Options* menu from the Admin Screen when my theme is activated. Is this possible and if so, how would I go about doing this? (Links to documentation welcome!)
- Remove the automatically registered action to wp_head that controls the color. Which action in particular would be responsible for this? (rsd_link, etc?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TwentyTen’s functions.php the custom background is added in twentyten_setup() which is called on the action `'after_setup_theme'`.

So, in your child theme, the following should remove the option completely:

```
// Higher priority to work after TwentyTen
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse12934_remove_custom_background', 20 );

function wpse12934_remove_custom_background()
{
    remove_custom_background();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Really basic question - where would I add this? :)

Comment: @ephemeral In your child theme’s functions.php.